# Install Monocross framework on Monodevelop for Mac

Tags: monodevelop, monocross

I'm trying to install the Monocross Framework on Monodevelop for Mac. The steps should be:
1. Start MonoDevelop.
2. In MonoDevelop, select Tools >> Add-in Manager and select the Gallery tab.
3. Select the MonoCross MonoDevelop Templates installation package for Mac OS.

But there is no "MonoCross MonoDevelop Templates" option.

some help, please ??

Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find this as well ( i viewed a demo of the book that contained the chapter and it doesn't say more then what you are telling).

So i searched around and found the code for monocross on [google code](http://code.google.com/p/monocross/source/checkout)  and checked out the trunk using svn.

There i learned that they only have finished the templates for the android side of things (!)
By opening the Monodevelop app content on my MBP.

All that's left after that is copying the

***trunk/MonoCross.Templates.MonoDevelop/MonoDevelop.MonoCross***

subdir and all its contents into the mac app bundle under

***Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/Addins***

and restart MonoDevelop.

After that you can see Monocross category under the C# section with (merely) the Android templates.

I hope this helps & brings to attention that they are not there yet...

Answer (score 1):

Installing the MonoCross Templates for MonoDevelop

1. Unzip the Templates.zip archive to a location on your Mac; the archive contains two files:

MonoDevelop.MonoCross_MD28.Templates_0.9.mpack - Templates for MonoDevelop 2.8
MonoDevelop.MonoCross.Templates_0.9.mpack - Templates for MonoDevelop 3.0

1. Open MonoDevelop, and click on the MonoDevelop menu.
2. Choose Add-in Manager… from the MonoDevelop menu.
3. In the Add-in Manager dialog, click Install from file…
4. Navigate to the location where you unzipped the template archive, and choose the .mpack package for your version of MonoDevelop.
5. Click Open, and Install... to install the templates; The MonoCross templates should appear in the left hand pane of the Add-in Manager dialog.
6. Click Close.

Now you should see a MonoCross option on your New Solution… and New File… options on your File menu.  You can use these templates to build MonoCross projects.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the MonoCross Templates for MonoDevelop

Unzip the Templates.zip archive to a location on your Mac; the archive contains two files:
MonoDevelop.MonoCross_MD28.Templates_0.9.mpack - Templates for MonoDevelop 2.8 MonoDevelop.MonoCross.Templates_0.9.mpack - Templates for MonoDevelop 3.0

1. Open MonoDevelop, and click on the MonoDevelop menu.
2. Choose Add-in Manager… from the MonoDevelop menu.
3. In the Add-in Manager dialog, click Install from file…
4. Navigate to the location where you unzipped the template archive, and choose the .mpack package for your version of MonoDevelop.
5. Click Open, and Install... to install the templates; The MonoCross templates should appear in the left hand pane of the Add-in Manager dialog.
6. Click Close.

Now you should see a MonoCross option on your New Solution… and New File… options on your File menu. You can use these templates to build MonoCross projects.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to little old documentation.

If you download the latest templates from www.monocross.net and get to readme , you will find following instructions which are pretty self explanatory.

Installing the MonoCross Templates for MonoDevelop

1. Unzip the Templates.zip archive to a location on your Mac; the archive contains two files:

MonoDevelop.MonoCross_MD28.Templates_0.9.mpack - Templates for MonoDevelop 2.8
MonoDevelop.MonoCross.Templates_0.9.mpack - Templates for MonoDevelop 3.0

1. Open MonoDevelop, and click on the MonoDevelop menu.
2. Choose Add-in Manager… from the MonoDevelop menu.
3. In the Add-in Manager dialog, click Install from file…
4. Navigate to the location where you unzipped the template archive, and choose the .mpack package for your version of MonoDevelop.
5. Click Open, and Install... to install the templates; The MonoCross templates should appear in the left hand pane of the Add-in Manager dialog.
6. Click Close.

Now you should see a MonoCross option on your New Solution… and New File… options on your File menu.  You can use these templates to build MonoCross projects.